# How to write a mathematical equality, equation or inequality that applies for the following probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

$$ P(A) = P(A|B) or  P(A)> P(A|B),or , P(A|B)$$

A is the event that the student is male, and B is the even that the student is over six feet tall.

SO for the first equation
$$ P(A) = P(A|B)$$
The probability of A is going to be the probability of a student being Male given that they are 6 feet tall?
How would i Create a mathematical equation?
$$S M = Students Male$$
$$S T = Six feet tall$$
 $$ P(M) = P(S M|S T) $$
I didn't really understand what the question was actually asking?
  Did I do this right?

Answer (score 0):

In general, $P(A) = P(A | B) P(B) + P(A | B^C) P(B^C)$. You can have $P(A) > P(A|B)$, $P(A) < P(A|B)$ and $P(A)=P(A|B)$.

In this case, you would expect the fact that you know that the height is more than 6 feet to make it much more likely than the general population to be male (men are typically about 5 inches taller than women, and women average around 5'4"). So, you'd expect P(male | over six feet tall) > P(male).

Comment: So, are you saying that all the equations are the same?, I understand a little bit, but could you explain it a bit more, your whole answer..and Thanks you for answering